# Can I use Raspberry Pi 3 SD card on Pi 4?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, pi-4, compatibility, software-compatibility

I'd like to move to the new raspberry pi because I need more performance. The current sd card I used on pi 2, ane now pi 3, and I'd like to ask if anyone tried running his pi 3 raspbian on pi 4 by just transferring the sd card. Pi 4 supports 64 bit, so I'm wondering whether there would be surprises.

Comment: Which operating system is on the sd card?

Comment: `Pi 4 supports 64 bit` technically the pi 3 (and second release of pi 2) are 64 bit capable chips

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Raspbian Stretch or earlier will not run on the Rpi4; a card containing Buster should work on all models.

[Buster - the new version of Raspbian](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/buster-the-new-version-of-raspbian/)

Comment: what makes you think OP is using Jessie? Seems an odd assumption (since the most recent previous version was stretch)

Answer (score 3):

The sd card could only just be transferred to the Pi4 if it had Raspbian Buster on it.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to upgrade the operating system system to Buster before you will be able to boot it on a pi4. if you have a working pi3 this is not all that difficult.

Comment: Have you ever tried to full-upgade a Raspbian version? Does it work for you without difficulties? The recommendation of the Raspberry Pi Foundation is to start with a new version from its image.

Comment: Much as I admire (and participate in) Stack Exchange, I have to say that many Raspberry Pi questions on here have already been very comprehensively answered on the Rasperry Pi official forum.

Comment: I done it on debian many times, it usually works. 98% success rate. Raspbian should be similar,